# CORS with reverse proxy Nginx server and nodejs won't work

Tags: node.js, nginx, http-headers, cors

I am working on a server with nodejs the server is running on a VPS I hire. From the localhost on my pc, I send a request to the server but all it gives me back is:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8086' is therefore not allowed access.

But I have this in my default file in de Nginx configuration:

```
    location / {
            proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
            proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';

            proxy_pass           http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_redirect       off;
            proxy_http_version   1.1;

            proxy_set_header     Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header     Connection  'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header     Host        $host;

            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

And here is an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present so whats the problem here.

As always thanks for helping!

Comment: Does your node server handle `options` requests? If not you are passing the request which is then rejected by the node server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a mistake in my nodejs code I didnt know that I needed to include 
`response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`