# Cors nginx and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, cors

I am using ReactJS on client side and NODEJS on the backend and nginx as a reverse proxy.
My nginx file looks like this.

```
server{
            listen 80;
            server_name www.trusting.com;
            location / {

                    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000';
                    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
                    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';

                    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;





        }


    }
```

Even thought the CORS is enabled on nginx i get error on ReactJS side when making REST calls.

```
Failed to load http://www.trusting.com/hey/signup: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: I think cors in just one place should suffice.

Comment: add this proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
also refer this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488382/cors-with-reverse-proxy-nginx-server-and-nodejs-wont-work"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According [to the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header), `proxy_set_header` attaches a header to the request. When it does so, the request has not yet entered your nodeJS application.

What you need to do is [attach a header to the response](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html). To do so, you need to use the `add_header` directive:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.trusting.com;
        location / {

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin' always;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also had to append 'Authorization' to 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'